# I installed JSDT for Eclipse - now how do I begin developing?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I installed the "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript" (which may be JSDT from IBM); I've also installed Aptana Studio 3 (which resembles Eclipse); I've installed Firebug for Firefox.  In all three cases, I'm at a complete loss as to how to go about actually writing some HTML that contains (or sucks in) some JavaScript, and then test and debug it!

(UPDATE) To give a better notion of where I am: I can create a New Project and a New Javascript file, and I can type `show("Hello World!);` into the document and I can press the green Run button, which gives me the inscrutable message about "the selection did not contain any resources that can run on a server."  Obviously they assume some preliminary knowledge, which is what I'm seeking.

This isn't meant to start a war about the best IDE, so let's assume that "Eclipse IDE for JavaScript" is a good choice (despite the fact that it apparently only supports ECMAScript 3!  well, one step at a time).  Can someone recommend a guide or tutorial that might, say, walk me through Hello World?

Comment: `<script>alert("Hello World!");</script>` The version of ECMAScript supported by your IDE won't stop you writing for a later version given that the JavaScript code is not compiled and will be executing in the browser. One possible approach is to just start solving the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems in JavaScript, writing the results out as HTML using `document.createElement()` and so forth. No, that's not a tutorial, but it'll force you to figure stuff out as you go. Google is your friend.

Comment: Well, thanks, but that's not very helpful.  I'm not averse to figuring stuff out as I go, and I googled this a _lot_ before posting in despair.  I have updated the original post to try and better illustrate the point at which I'm stuck.

Comment: I seem to have two identities on SO.  This is the OP.  Regarding Project Euler, to clarify, I know how to program.  I'm missing some elementary knowledge of how to use Eclipse to develop (edit & debug) JavaScript to run in a browser.

Comment: Put some actual HTML pages into your project and try running them, don't run the JavaScript file directly. Did the Eclipse install not come with a sample project or two?